# How to encrypt TextField before saving in database

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-admin

Here I am Trying to create Model where i can save Password, here my model:

```
class Server(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
    ip2 = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True, blank=True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    password = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    ssh_key = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='Keys/')
```

till now i read lot of blogs and posts but i haven't found any good way to save encrypted text in database

i was trying this method but it is also not working for me please check my View.py below,

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
class HostCreate(CreateView):
    model = Server
    template_name = 'inventory/host_create.html'
    form_class = HostForm

    # after getting POST data of fields (name, hostname, ip, pass, key) adding user and saving
    def form_valid(self, form):
        host = form.save(commit=False)
        host.user = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
        host.password = self.ecrypt(host.password)
        host.save()
        return redirect('inventory:hosts')

    def ecrypt(self, password): # need password and return cipher password
        key = 'wgjSSyfVKgz0EjyTilqeJSaANLDu7TzHKdpAXUeZPbM='
        cipher_suite = Fernet(key)
        cipher_text = cipher_suite.encrypt(password)
        return cipher_text
```

here i am getting error,

```
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    data must be bytes.
Exception Location:     /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/fernet.py in _encrypt_from_parts, line 55
```

Is there any builtin django functionality for password field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using django-encrypted-fields Packages
Steps are :

on Project Root directory open terminal and Execute commands.

1. Install Package django-encrypted-fields

   ```
   $ pip install django-encrypted-fields
   ```
2. Create a basic keyczar keyset. AES-256 in this case.

   ```
   $ mkdir fieldkeys
   $ keyczart create --location=fieldkeys --purpose=crypt
   $ keyczart addkey --location=fieldkeys --status=primary --size=256
   ```
3. Add settings In your settings.py

   ```
   ENCRYPTED_FIELDS_KEYDIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'fieldkeys')
   ```
4. Now in models.py

   ```
   from django.db import models
   import encrypted_fields
   class Server(models.Model):
       password = encrypted_fields.EncryptedCharField(max_length=500)
   ```

for more details please visit [here](https://github.com/defrex/django-encrypted-fields)

hope this will help someone in future

Comment: When i try `keyczart create --location=fieldkeys --purpose=crypt`
I get error `Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Generating private key sets...")?`

Comment: @Aseem That's because your using Python3 and the code is not yet made compatible for Python3, use Python2 if you need to use this plugin

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in two possible ways.

1. Write custom save method for your model like this

   ```
   class Server(models.Model):
       user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
       hostname = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
       ip = models.GenericIPAddressField()
       ip2 = models.GenericIPAddressField(null=True, blank=True)
       user_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
       password = models.TextField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
       ssh_key = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='Keys/')

       def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
           if not self.pk:
               # encrypt_field_value_here
           super(Server, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
   ```
2. You can use custom model fields. You can get documentation on this from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-model-fields/). Also check `BaseEncryptedField` from [here](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master@%7B2016-06-10%7D/django_extensions/db/fields/encrypted.py#L22).

You can also use [this](https://github.com/defrex/django-encrypted-fields) package.

Comment: What does `not self.pk` mean?

Comment: the primary key of current object. For new object, this will be None.

Answer (score 1):

For the password field, Django uses its own hashing. You can [change](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/passwords/) it though.

There are a few encryption methods in Django. You can use them like AES. It can be imported from crypto cipher.

Otherwise you can use the default [Django `Signer`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signing/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [django-fernet-fields](https://django-fernet-fields.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library, which defines `EncryptedXXXField` for you:

```
from django.db import models
from fernet_fields import EncryptedTextField


class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = EncryptedTextField()
```

The values are saved with symmetric encryption, and by default uses `SECRET_KEY` as en encryption key, so all you need to do is keep your `SECRET_KEY` constant over time.